# Angular ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDOM doesn't isolate css styles

Tags: angular, shadow-dom

I've read that `ShadowDOM` isolates the shadow dom tree from external css so i've tried to play around with it in Angular using `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom`, but it seems like the global css are still leaking into the Shadow DOM.

Kindly see the code here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/shadow-dom-test?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
import { Component, VERSION, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
}
```

After that, setting any css in `style.css` will affect the elements under `AppComponent` even though the encapsulation is set to `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom`and the component is contained  under ShadowDom tree.

See the screenshot below, Font-size is inherited by elements under ShadowDOM

[image]

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: What are those `some css`? Can you please specify the issue?

Comment: @deepakchethan i'm using google-chrome

Comment: @yurzui, yeah, the global styles under style.css affects the elements under `AppComponent` even though it has `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom`.  I've always thought that global styles won't affect elements under ShadowDom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [w3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-scoping-1/#inheritance)

> 3.3.2 Inheritance
>
> The top-level elements of a shadow tree inherit from their host
> element

What this means is that inheritable styles, like color or  font-size among others, continue to inherit in shadow DOM, will pierce the shadow DOM and affect your component's styling.

You can force it back to initial state by using

**app.component.ts**

```
:host {
  all: initial;
}
```

It will prevent inheritance without affecting other CSS defined within the ShadowDOM.

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/shadow-dom-test-mukmxb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)**

See also:

- https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/style-shadow-dom#use-inheritance-from-document-level-styles
- https://css-tricks.com/playing-shadow-dom/
- https://lamplightdev.com/blog/2019/03/26/why-is-my-web-component-inheriting-styles/

Comment: I always put the **https://lamplightdev.com/blog/2019/03/26/why-is-my-web-component-inheriting-styles/** blog first, it is the best written explanation

Comment: Awesome! Now, it all makes sense. Thanks a lot. Is there any way to automatically add `:host { all: initial }` on creating of a component?

Comment: You can create your own schematic for component where you can have this css